# C# Xamarin.Forms - Intercept Application.MainPage Setter?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, interceptor, getter-setter

In a Xamarin Forms project, I've been able to successfully intercept the `ContentPage.Content` property (which is a public property with a getter and setter). I have a class `BaseContentPage`, which inherits from `ContentPage`, and overrides the `Content` property like so:

```
public new View Content
{
    set
    {
        // create a wrapper around the value of Content
        // ... someWrapper = ...

        // set Content to the wrapped content
        base.Content = someWrapper;
    }
}
```

I think the 2 key points are: using the `new` keyword, and using `base.Content = ...`

I'm trying to do the same thing with the `Application.MainPage` property in my App.cs file (which inherits from Application), like so:

```
public new Page MainPage
{
    get
    {
        return base.MainPage;
    }
    set
    {
        // do something before navigating to the new page
        // ...

        base.MainPage = value;
    }
}
```

But my app has some strange behavior - when I navigate to some of my existing pages, they are showing up as blank pages (just a white screen). If I remove the getter, and only have a setter, it seems to work fine. In the getter, I've also tried `return value`, but that gives me the error `The name 'value' does not exist in the current context`.

Is that the proper way to intercept a public property with a getter and setter?

Comment: why is it crashing?  What is the exception?

Comment: When I copy your exact code into a new project it works fine. Are you sure the exception isn't coming from whatever custom code you're running in the setter?

Comment: Ugh, weird - ok so now it's working...sometimes. Some of my existing pages are showing up blank now (just white screen).

Comment: Not completely surprising that this "pseudo-override" could have unexpected or inconsistent behavior. My thought would be that if this was intended by authors of `Application` class, `MainPage` property would have been marked virtual. Maybe just create a method in your derived app class that does what you want, then sets "un-overridden" `MainPage`?

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to achieve? There may be a better approach if you share what your desired end result is. IOW, why do you need a wrapper around the content? And why do you need to run your own code every time you set the MainPage? Could this code be run prior to your setting the MainPage with the built-in setter?

Comment: I'm trying to perform an action every time a page is left. Specifically, I'm handling scanner interactions, which involves subscribing via MessagingCenter. Every time I'm finished with a page, I need to *un*subscribe from the scanner. I don't want to do this manually every time.